# How to use project methods with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, winforms, roslyn

I am using Roslyn to run C# code from text.

It works, but I can't figure out how can I use my project class methods, didn't find a way to reference my project methods. I can't use a dll as there too many classes and forms I need to use.

For exmaple, using the Number set method, or the DoMultiAction() method inside the roslyn ExecuteUserCodeTest() text code. How to do that they will be referenced?

Is it even possible? Any explanation or example will be appreciated.

My Code:

```
namespace bot1
{
class Testing
{
    private int number;

    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set { this.number = value; }
    }

    public int DoMultiAction(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 * num2 * Number;
    }

    public void ExecuteUserCodeTest()
    {
        String text = @"
        using System;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        namespace RoslynCompileSample
        {
            public class Writer
            {
                public void Write(String text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(text);
                }
            }
        }";
        // define source code, then parse it (to the type used for compilation)
        SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(text);
        // define other necessary objects for compilation
        string assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        MetadataReference[] references = new MetadataReference[]
        {
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location),
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Drawing.Point).Assembly.Location),
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox).Assembly.Location),
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof (ScriptManagerHandler.ScriptHandler).Assembly.Location)
        };

        // analyse and generate IL code from syntax tree
        CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
            assemblyName,
            syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
            references: references,
            options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // write IL code into memory
            EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);

            if (!result.Success)
            {
                // handle exceptions
                IEnumerable<Diagnostic> failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                    diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                    diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                String error = "";
                foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in failures)
                {
                    error += "" + diagnostic.Id + ", " + diagnostic.GetMessage() + "\n";
                }
                if (error != "")
                    MessageBox.Show(error);
            }
            else
            {
                // load this 'virtual' DLL so that we can use
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());

                // create instance of the desired class and call the desired function
                Type type = assembly.GetType("RoslynCompileSample.Writer");
                object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                type.InvokeMember("Write",
                    BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                    null,
                    obj,
                    new object[] { "Hello World" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you not underatand about following : type.InvokeMember("Write",
                    BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                    null,
                    obj,
                    new object[] { "Hello World" });  Right now it is a local variable.  To use in other modules you would need to make the variables type and obj more accessible.

Comment: @jdweng What do you mean? I want to use a method outside of roslyn text code, not from the inside.

Comment: You want to use the variables inside ExecuteUserCodeTest in other places in your code.  Either return the values or create a class and put the variables in global space instead of inside the method.

Comment: @jdweng I think we are not thinking the same or I'm confused. I've edited my question and code to make it more clear. May you look and if you did understand my question right can you please give me a little example?

Comment: So put in the top of the class instead of the method following : Type type {get;set;} object obj {get; set;};  Then method wold just be : type = assembly.GetType("RoslynCompileSample.Writer"); obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);